# Excel checkbox dropdown fill option in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, box

I created my list and inserted that into list box and all seems well and the list box has all fields I need. Issue I'm having is my code...I've looked at it for hours and can't figure out what the issue is with my VBA code:

Here's a screenshot of my excel sheet. Basically cells G1:G7 is where I need the user to be able to select a dropdown with a checkbox and have it fill in with each data separated by a comma. Like 12345,12546,12345 etc...

[image: Excel screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
Sub Rectangle3_Click()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20191114
Dim xSelShp As Shape, xSelLst As Variant, I As Integer
Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set xLstBox = ActiveSheet.Drop_Down2
If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
    xLstBox.Visible = True
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Please select below:"
Else
    xLstBox.Visible = False
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Please select below:"
    For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If xLstBox.Selected(I) = True Then
        xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & ";" & xSelLst
        End If
    Next I
    If xSelLst <> "" Then
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
    Else
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question - firstly, please include the row numbers and column letters in your screenshot if you want to point out a specific cell like G2 in your instance (I can't tell what cell G2 is referencing in your image). Also, could you mind elaborating a bit more on what your current code does? What is `Rectangle3`?

Comment: Sorry I updated the pic: Rectangle3 was a shape I assigned to the Macro to where user clicks on the shape and the dropdown option appears and the user clicks which every values that apply and it takes that and inputs it into another cell and ads a "," after each value selected

Comment: It sounds as if you are hoping for behavior much like the out-of-the-box data validation in excel where selecting a cell provides a dropdown of appropriate values for the cell.  But you need your list to be multi-select, and then the cell's resulting value should be a comma-separated list?

Comment: I actually selected the list box and did a right click and gave it the perimeters for the drop down list and selected the multi-select option. I have the list with the checkboxes, my issue is getting that to populate in a cell once a user has checked which ones they need and separating each selection by a comma.